# Cannot restore SQL Server 2008R2 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I took a backup of the database on a disk from a server that I do not have online access to. Trying to restore the database on my local machine using:

```
RESTORE DATABASE MYDB FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.WXVMSSQL\MSSQL\Backup\mydb' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Directory lookup for the file
>   "D:\MSSQL2008\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydb.mdf" failed with
>   the operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 File
>   'LOGICAL_DEV_Data' cannot be restored to
>   'D:\MSSQL2008\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydb.mdf'. Use WITH
>   MOVE to identify a valid location for the file. Msg 5133, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 1 Directory lookup for the file
>   "D:\MSSQL2008\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydb.ldf" failed with
>   the operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 File
>   'LOGICAL_DEV_Log' cannot be restored to
>   'D:\MSSQL2008\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydb.ldf'. Use WITH
>   MOVE to identify a valid location for the file. Msg 3119, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 1 Problems were identified while planning for the
>   RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details. Msg 3013, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

It seems to be looking at the D: drive which was the server drive I
copied the backup. I tried the same command above

```
WITH MOVE 'C:\.....mdf' and MOVE 'C:\.....ldf'
```

I get the following:

> Msg 3183, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 RESTORE detected an error on page
>   (64000:1024) in database "mydb" as read from the backup set. Msg 3013,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

It is also hanging with the status Restoring ... MS server management studio, I also tried **CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR** still to no avail. any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: "**Msg 3183 ... detected an error on page ...***"  sounds like SQL Server is trying to restore from a *corrupted* backup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, this database resided on a drive D:; the file paths are part of the backup. (The intention is that the most usual case is probably to restore a database on the same server it was backuped from).

This explains the 'WITH MOVE'-clause, you are requested to add.

- Have you checked, if the paths given are valid on your system?
- Do you run the same or a later release of MS SQL Server than the system the backup was taken on? You can find out with

  select @@version;

Comment: Hi Mat, Yes I can confirm it is 2008 R2, check the path ok too

Comment: This is just a vague guess: please try the select @@version command. The internal formats often depend on a minor release number (not covered by "2008R2").

(On the other hand: the server should tell you, if there was a version conflict.)

Comment: Thanks Mat for alerting me about the minor release. I will do as soon as I get access. Will be back

Comment: here is the the version of the backup server : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64) and the restore : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)

Comment: So it seems the build number of the backup server is larger than the one from the restore box. (6000.34 and 1600.1).

However, apart from this being part of the problem or not, it'd probably be a good idea to install SP3 on your box, anyway. You might want to give this a try, but beware that (to the best of my knowledge) this cannot be undone.

If that can't be done, I'd be happy to try and restore the file here on my lab server (provided the db is not larger than few GB), I have a SS2016 version here.

Comment: Thanks. I issued the command `RESTORE VERIFYONLY from disk = N'D:\MSSQL2008\Backup\MYDB_backup.bak'` where D drive is the destination folder after a backup process. I got the following result
`The backup set on file 1 is valid` issuing the same command after copying the back to the removable disk gave this `Msg 3189, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Damage to the backup set was detected.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.`.

Comment: I guess the backup copy on the removable disk is corrupt, I have to conclude.

Comment: Good idea, well done! Unfortunately, you're probably right.

Do you have a tool to compare binary files? (If they are identical, there must be another problem. may simply the stick is dead.)

Answer (score 0):

You need check drive using `xp_fixeddrives`

You have to see file list

```sql
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = 'D:\logshipping\DEMO.bak' WITH FILE = 1
```

You have to use move option for restoration.

```
RESTORE DATABASE DEMO_
FROM DISK = 'D:\logshipping\DEMO.bak'
WITH
MOVE 'Demo' TO 'D:\MSSQL_DATA\DEMO\DEMO_Winmedicare.mdf',
MOVE 'Demo_log' TO 'E:\MSSQL_LOG\DEMO_Winmedicare\DEMO_log.ldf', norecovery ;
```